# Android NDK: Compiling errors using libpcap for Android - functions "not declared in this scope"

Tags: android, compiler-errors, libpcap, android-ndk

I'm trying to port Jnetpcap (a java wrapper for libpcap with JNI) to Android. I've managed to compile libpcap as a static library using the source code in this repository: https://github.com/android/platform_external_libpcap and I obtained libpcap.a

When trying to compile Jnetpcap as a shared library (and linking with libpcap.a) I'm getting errors because some libpcap's functions "weren't declared in this scope".
Those functions are: pcap_create(), pcap_activate(), pcap_can_set_rfmon(), pcap_set_buffer_size(), pcap_set_promisc(), pcap_set_snaplen() and pcap_set_timeout().

Those functions exist in the original version of libpcap (the one which the packet libpcap-dev provides) but seems that the android's version doesn't have them. The same source files of Jnetpcap can be compiled for intel x86 and x64 platforms without problems.

Am I doing something wrong? Are those functions really missing?

I hope any of you guys know how to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like that version 0.9.8 of libpcap doesn't support these functions. Versions >= 1.0.0 contains them. So right now you have 2 possibilities. Compile newer version of libpcap by modification Android.mk for old version a little to include new files. Or downgrade jnetpcap to version that support old libpcap. Libpcap 0.9.8 if from 2007 so you should choose jnetpcap from around this year as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I downgraded to Jnetpcap 1.2 and it worked with libpcap 0.9.8. I'm making some tests but it seems that I've got a working port of Jnetpcap 1.2 for Android.

It won't support live captures because the App can't be run as root but the parsing functionalities should work nicely.

Comment: @Jimix I am trying to use jnetpcap on Android 9(armhf boards), how did you port it please? I can't find a way to cross compile jnetpcap :s

Comment: @Jimix did you manage to capture packets without root privilege ?